# PHP, PDO, and MySQL - Cannot establish connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first time using PHP to read/write to a MySQL database and I'm stuck on step one. I am following the w3schools guide and created a php file named "welcome.php" which I can view by navigating to `localhost/dbpopulate/welcome.php`.

The HTML / PHP for this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "default";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=user", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?> 


</body>
</html>
```

I can access this 'user' database using the 'default' password without issue from inside and outside of my network on a multitude of devices. When I attempt to access the page, I receive this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\DBPopulate\welcome.php on line 11

Line 11 is:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=user", $username, $password);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `dbname=user` are you sure of the database name? and that the code you posted is in fact that? I can't see this failing. Make sure there's no hidden unicode also.

Comment: You would normally get `syntax error, unexpected '$whatever'` is you have not ended a previous line with a semicolon, or have not closed quotes. Neither is the case here... Double-check in your actual code, tho.

Comment: I don't think you're telling us the whole story here and how else you're using this. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: This is quite literally it. The username is five digit number that matches the name of the database. The password is default. The host is localhost (have also tried 127.0.0.1).

Comment: Triple-check your code. You surely have a stray character or perhaps a "smart quote" in your actual code. The code you have given here would not produce the error you are getting.

Comment: Oh, and you absolutely should not allow remote access without an encrypted connection, and even then not with the password "default". That is begging to get your machine hacked.

Comment: I understand that, this is not in production / even close to it. I am just simply trying to open a connection to a MySQL database. I went ahead and created a new user '12345' with the password 'default', from host set to '%' and that one does not work either. I'm not hiding anything and this is simply exactly what I posted :(.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thank you for the suggestion about hidden Unicode, there were characters present on the copy from w3schools that I identified in NetBeans. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Eric Aahhh, I had a Spidey sense about that. Glad I was able to help, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: @EdCottrell Seems it was a unicode character after all (see new comments) and the duplicate you chose to close the question with, doesn't cover that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I disagree; the [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539535/2057919) in the duplicate still explains the error, and this text is still valid: "A problem with the syntax of your program, such as leaving a semicolon off of the end of a statement or, like the case above, missing the `.` operator." In any case, there are many questions here with solutions addressing this problem. I've added a couple as additional duplicates. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/2057919) in particular is helpful and addresses invisible unicode characters.

Comment: @EdCottrell [The second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/2057919) is indeed the correct one. Thanks for finding the right one Ed, *cheers*